# Writing EXIF information into JPEGs with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, camera, jpeg, exif

I'm looking to use react-native to capture photos from iOS and Android devices and then to record additional metadata about those images that is captured in the context of the application.

One thought was to use the built in EXIF information available in JPEGs and write to it directly, which would obviate the need for an additional database.

Is there a straightforward way to be able to *write* EXIF information (e.g. Title and Description fields) from react-native?

Comment: If you can write binary data in react-native you can create Exif data.

Comment: @user3344003 right, but to do you, you'd have to be intricately familiar with the organization of the EXIF data in a JPEG. At that point, wouldn't it just be easier to use a separate database to track metadata and link it back to the relevant file?

Comment: any update on writing exif ? thx

Comment: Since [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/#readfilefilepath-string-encoding-string-promisestring) reads binary data back as base64 and the complexity of trying to manage that in JS is too much of a pain, I just end up sending it to the backend, where it can be post-processed on the server much more easily.